# flow meter that displays litres per hour

Tags: microcontroller, programming, timer, interrupts

for the past 2 week iv just started my first ever project to make a c program on the software called mikroc where i would get pulses in from the flow meter and calculate the flow rate of how much litres flows every hour which then outputs to the lcd, however, after using a timer of 100ms and an interrupt that occurs that does the calculations and displays on the screen. i get lots of 0's on lcd and when the water flows through the meter...i get a change of 1 . thats all. please guys i would very much appreciate it if i get help on this. 
also how do i read the input signal becuase i may have done it wrong.
the input signal is connected to RB7 as i have chaned the interrupt pin.

pic16f877a datasheet: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/e...Doc/39582b.pdf
water flow meter datasheet: http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/datash...rs/YF-S201.pdf

this is the code:

```
//Prescaler 1:4; TMR1 Preload = 15536; Actual Interrupt Time : 100 ms
volatile unsigned int val;
char num [20];
int calc;
void InitTimer1(){
  T1CON         = 0x21;
  TMR1IF_bit         = 0;
  TMR1H         = 0x3C;
  TMR1L         = 0xB0;
  TMR1IE_bit         = 1;
  INTCON         = 0xC8;
}

void Interrupt(){
  if ((TMR1IF_bit) && (RBIF_bit)){
    TMR1IF_bit = 0;
    RBIF_bit   = 0;
    TMR1H         = 0x3C;
    TMR1L         = 0xB0;
    val= PORTB.F7;                //read the input signal and assign it to val
    Calc = (val * 60 / 7.5);          //calculations for the flow rate per hour
    longinttostrwithzeros(calc,num);       //displaying on screen
    Lcd_Out(1, 3, num );
  }
}

void main() {
     Lcd_Init();
     TRISB=0b10000000;       //initiallizing rb7 as the interrupt
     PORTB=0;
     InitTimer1();            //100ms timer
}
```

Comment: This question is very difficult to read.

Comment: The link for Datasheet of Flowmeter is not working. And You need to add an empty `while(1) { } ` in `main` if you are not doing any processing there.

Comment: Too sloppily written. Screw this. -1, closing, and moving on.

Answer (score 2):

I don't speak PIC, but it appears that you are simply assigning the present state of the flow meter output to "val".  That state can only be 0 or 1.

You need to count pulses from the flow meter over some period, then calculate the flow rate.

I would probably use two interrupts: one from a 100 mS or 1 sec timer, and one from the flow meter output.  The flow meter interrupt would simply increment a counter on each interrupt.  The timer interrupt would calculate the flow based on the count, then clear the counter.